# How to get odd hours to even hours in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have such a dataframe with "normal" steps of two hours between the timestamps. But sometimes there are unfortunately gaps within my data. Because of that I would like to round timestamps with odd hours (01:00, 03:00 etc.) to even hours (02:00, 04:00 etc.). `Time` is my `index` column.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
Time    Values      
2021-10-24 22:00:00 2
2021-10-25 00:00:00 4
2021-10-25 02:00:00 78
2021-10-25 05:00:00 90
2021-10-25 07:00:00 1
```

How can I get a dataframe like this?

```
Time    Values      
2021-10-24 22:00:00 2
2021-10-25 00:00:00 4
2021-10-25 02:00:00 78
2021-10-25 06:00:00 90
2021-10-25 08:00:00 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "Time" is a column (and not the index), you can use `dt.ceil`:

```
df["Time"] = df["Time"].dt.ceil("2H")

>>> df
                 Time  Values
0 2021-10-24 22:00:00       2
1 2021-10-25 00:00:00       4
2 2021-10-25 02:00:00      78
3 2021-10-25 06:00:00      90
4 2021-10-25 08:00:00       2
```

Alternatively, if you want to ensure that the data contains every 2-hour interval, you could `resample`:

```
df = df.resample("2H", on="Time", closed="right").sum()

>>> df
                     Values
Time                       
2021-10-24 22:00:00       2
2021-10-25 00:00:00       4
2021-10-25 02:00:00      78
2021-10-25 04:00:00       0
2021-10-25 06:00:00      90
2021-10-25 08:00:00       2
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DateTimeIndex.floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html)  or [`DateTimeIndex.ceil`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.ceil.html)  with a frequency string `2H` depending if you want to down or upsample.

```
df.index = df.index.ceil('2H')
>>> df
                     Values
Time                       
2021-10-24 22:00:00       2
2021-10-25 00:00:00       4
2021-10-25 02:00:00      78
2021-10-25 06:00:00      90
2021-10-25 08:00:00       1
```